# nmcli not installed, how to add ssid and password?

Tags: command-line, wireless, nmcli

I am trying to use my hotspot to upgrade this computer, but I don't know how to add the ssid and password. I only have the terminal to work with.
I want to go from Ubuntu 17.04 to Lubuntu 18.04.

Pentium 4 512Mb ram, 40Gb HD

How can one mount the wifi adapter, and configure it.... without a desktop, OR network manager?

Comment: can you check if it has `wifi-menu` or not, and if it does try `sudo wifi-menu -o` to connect to a wireless network. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: @ Prathu Baronia thx for the reply, and no it does not have wifi-menu.

Comment: can you add the output of `apropos -a network` to the post?

Comment: apropos -a network gets me "network: nothing appropriate."

Comment: I think you need to perform an offline installation of network tools here. Grab the zip, copy it to the .machine and then ask apt to install from that zip file. Then you would get at least nmcli

Comment: Prathu Baronia, do you have any recommendations for where to go to get the offline tools? I am searching. I am ready with a USB drive...just not sure what is best.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I had a copy of lubuntu-18.04-desktop.iso in my home directory. I umounted a fresh USB. Then
sudo dd bs=4M if=lubuntu-18.04-desktop.iso of=/dev/sdc conv=fdatasync
There was some hassle because at first I sent the output to /dev/sdc1 which was what I was used to calling the USB. 
As soon as I got the USB booting the computer, the wifi adapter lit up and up up and away we went!
Thanks for your help!!!